# Canvas lags each time I draw the same thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm fiddling around with the canvas tag making a bunch of rectangles that I can click and drag around but after 4 or 5 times of dragging, the canvas starts to lag  a lot, is there something I'm missing?

The first time you move it it's perfect, but the rest aren't as smooth.

Maybe I'm not clearing the canvas correctly, but is there any other better way?

```
$(document).on("mousedown", '#myCanvas', () => {
    mouseDown = true;
    $(document).on("mousemove", (event) => {
        if (mouseDown) {
            if (mouseX && mouseY) {

                // Clear the canvas
                canvasCtx.save();
                canvasCtx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasCtx.canvas.width, canvasCtx.canvas.height);
                canvasCtx.restore();

                // Translate to new x & y
                canvasCtx.translate((canvasX + (event.pageX - mouseX)), (canvasY + (event.pageY - mouseY)));

                                // Fill with previous generated rectangles
                for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                    canvasCtx.fillStyle = boxes[i].color;
                    canvasCtx.fillRect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);
                }

                // Paint
                canvasCtx.stroke();

            }

            // Get last mouse movement
            mouseX = event.pageX;
            mouseY = event.pageY;
        }
    })
})
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nielrock/t31skc5d/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the mousemove eventListener out of the mouse down eventListener just like the mouseup.
I don't know but seems it worked

Comment: How did I not thinked of that... Thank you so much!!